# ios Add data to UITableView in milliseconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

I have the following problem.
I created a UITableView, with own Cell´s.
For The Cell i created a xib-file with 4 labels inside.
I also create a own tableviewsource with a add funciton.

Now I have the problem, that every 10 ms i have to add new data to the table source, the new data comes from a thread.
I have to display the updated table source.
For this i use

```
table.Reload();
```

When I try to update the table everytime when i add data, the GUI block total.

When I try to update the table lets say every 500 ms the GUI blocks every 500ms.
Is there any "better" way to display such huge amount of data.

I am using Monotouch with Xamarin Studio, but i would also like to have answers from xcode.
Here are some code snippets.

The Table cell:

```
public class CanMessageTableSource: UITableViewSource
{
    public List<CanMesssageForGui> _messages;

    bool groupMessages;

    public CanMessageTableSource()
    {
        _messages = new List<CanMesssageForGui>();
    }

    public void ClearMessages()
    {
         _messages.Clear();
    }

    public void AddMessage(CanMessage message)
    {
        var incomingGuiMessage = message.ToGuiCanMessage ();
        _messages.Add(incomingGuiMessage);
    }

    public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _messages.Count;
    }   

    public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 16;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        try
        {
            CanMessageCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("CanMessageCell") as CanMessageCell;

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new CanMessageCell();
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CanMessageCell", cell, null);
                cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as CanMessageCell;
            }

            var msg = _messages.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
            cell.SetData(msg, GroupMessages);

            return cell;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("CanMessageTableSource", "" + ex, HorschLibrary.Core.LogTypes.Error);
            var cell = new CanMessageCell();
            var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CanMessageCell", cell, null);
            cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as CanMessageCell;

            if (_messages.Count >= indexPath.Row)
            {
                var msg = _messages.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
                cell.SetData(msg, GroupMessages);
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }

}
```

The View Controller

```
partial class DeviceMessagesController : UIViewController
{
    private BluetoothService _bluetoothService;


    public DeviceMessagesController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
          _tableSource = new CanMessageTableSource();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        _bluetoothService = BluetoothService.GetInstance();
        _bluetoothService.NewMessageOccurred += HandleNewMessageOccurred;
    }


    //will be called i worst case every milli second
    void HandleNewMessageOccurred (object sender, IBluetoothMessage e)
    {
        if(e.MessageType == BluetoothMessageType.CanFrame)
        {
            _messageReceived = true;
            var canMessage = ((BluetoothCanMessage)e).Message;
            InvokeOnMainThread(()=> 
            {
              _tableSource.AddMessage(canMessage);
              tableMessges.ReloadData();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reload all rows in response to adding new data. You should add new rows only instead of reloading all - the normal way of doing it would be to call

`beginUpdates`

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`
 (as many times as you need)

`endUpdates`

In this way the table view will not reload all data just add the new rows, which should be much more efficient.

Comment: should i call this inserRowsAtIndexPaths evertime when i add a new message to table source?

Comment: Yes I think this would be the simplest way.

Comment: looks fine, is there also a way that i can automatically scroll to the lates element, when adding new message?

Comment: You could call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` but since you are adding data continuously it would make using the table impossible - if I want to scroll back to some item it would automatically scroll to new rows again.

Comment: yes tableview has this method [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:sectionNumber] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]

Comment: hi I hope you will read again. What i have done now is specify a max number ob table entries. when this maximum is reached i delete the first entry and add the new one at the end. It is possible that this appears within some millis. The problem is the the table is now "flushing". Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: If you modify table continuously you may expect some visual effects. I think that the problem is this continuous updates in the first place. Did you consider not doing them and instead updating after some action by the user?

Comment: user action is not a option. the goal is to display a trace of lets say incoming tcp-ip messages.

Comment: Then do not update that often, but try what happens if you do it each second or two.